# Can we use a component inside another component in current version of Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am looking to use component inside another component in angular2 current version(V2.2.0)

But previously we had option to use component inside another component using following code.

```
import { AnotherComponent } from './another-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  directives: [AnotherComponent],
  template: '<div>Something there<another></another></div>'
})
export class OtherComponent {
}
```

But when i am trying the same it does not work it throws template compile error.

Is this feature removed now?
OR
There is another way to do same?

ERROR MESSAGE

> 1. If 'navigation' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'navigation' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message. ("

Comment: Can you add your error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the `AnotherComponent` in your Parent **Module** in **declarations**

```
declarations: [
  AnotherComponent 
]
```

Comment: but we dont have attribute for component of name declarations?

Comment: Then you have to add the attribute ;)

Answer (score 4):

make a file with all your component like this

```
import {
    LoginComponent
} from './loginComponent/login.component';
import {
    adduserComponent
} from './core/adduserComponent/adduser.component';
import {
    TemplateComponent
} from './core/template.component';
import {
    DashboardComponent
} from './core/dashboard/dashboard';
import {
   HeadComponent
} from './core/headComponent/head.component';


export const ALL_DECLARATIONS = [
    LoginComponent,
    adduserComponent,
    TemplateComponent,
    HeadComponent,
    ChangeHeadComponent
];
```

and import ALL_DECLARATIONS in your parent Module file

```
import { ALL_DECLARATIONS } from './filename';
```

and use

```
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            ...ALL_DECLARATIONS
        ],
        providers: [
            ...ROUTES_PROVIDERS
        ],
        bootstrap: [
            AppComponent
        ]
    })
export class AppModule {}
```

use Spread Operator so you don't have to import all component file in module file

```
let cde = ['c', 'd', 'e'];
let scale = ['a', 'b', ...cde, 'f', 'g'];  // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```